# Displaying data from tweepy python file within django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, tweepy

I have been playing around with the [tweepy package](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/docs/getting_started.rst) all day. I have it working in a .py file however I would like to display twitter data I get from tweepy in a view to show information in a table. I'm fairly new to this and I amn't exactly sure what the architecture for for mapping my testingtweepy.py file live in my django environment looks like. Here is the code I am trying to show in Django as testingtweepy.py:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy.auth import OAuthHandler

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

The goal is to grab the data from public_tweets and store it in the Django database so I can furthermore display the data at a future time.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please read about views and models in django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consuming APIs is fairly simple. You don't need to create any models or forms, unless you want to save response data.

1. Create view in `views.py`

   ```
   def home_timeline(request):
       auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
       auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

       api = tweepy.API(auth)

       public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

       return render(request, 'public_tweets.html', {'public_tweets': public_tweets})
   ```
2. Create html template `public_tweets.html`

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
       {% for tweet in public_tweets %}
         <p>{{ tweet.text }}</p>
       {% endfor %}
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

   This is just a basic example. It will render `text` field from `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json`
3. Add url to `urls.py`

   ```
   url(r'^home_timeline/$',views.home_timeline, name='home_timeline')
   ```

Comment: If I want to save the response to database, how should I do it?